# Ext4 and NTFS partitions recovery

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery

I had two partitions in NTFS and one in ext4 (Ubuntu 12.04 installed one week ago), something gone wrong and the OS couln'd start. I tried to reinstall a new version and by mistake choosed the option to install the system on the previous, he erased all the data I had (NTFS and ext4), I wanted to format only the ext4 partition. On the NTFS partitions I had very important data. How can I recover it? What applications should I use?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An application that I have personally found useful is testdisk. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

It is a command line utility, but very powerful.

Comment: Thanks, I installed and scanning with it, 20% and found one partition, i'm really happy :P waiting for another partition

Comment: This must be run *on a live CD/DVD/USB*, [not on the OS that has overwritten the valuable data](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#CAUTION). Installing more software in a partition that exists over the lost data will make it much harder (or totally impossible) to recover the data.